# Distribute input value to table columns based on another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

Here's the dilemma that I have:
Declare @dis_qty = 20; --input

the table has values:

| id | sk_code | o_qty | pick_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sk_123 | 10 | null |
| 2 | sk_123 | 5 | null |
| 3 | sk_123 | 17 | null |

Needed update query with below result

| id | sk_code | o_qty | pick_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sk_123 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | sk_123 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | sk_123 | 17 | 5 |

pick_qty column should be assign based on input value i.e, @dis_qty.

note: without using loops

Answer (score 0):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax to update the table from a query that returns the running total:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET pick_qty = CASE 
  WHEN t2.running_total <= @dis_qty THEN t1.o_qty 
  ELSE NULLIF(MAX(@dis_qty - t2.running_total + t1.o_qty, 0), 0) 
END   
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(o_qty) OVER (ORDER BY id) running_total
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE sk_code = 'sk_123' AND pick_qty IS NULL
) AS t2
WHERE t2.id = t1.id;
```

Replace `@dis_qty` with the value that you want.

See the [demo](https://sqliteonline.com/#share=33e3874e5d9d088da589587cb5f2a1564c776db9dbce74020a4b8042322f4c59).